# PWA: How to solve web app manifest or service worker error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, progressive-web-apps

**I'm trying to turn my web app into a pwa, but I keep getting the same error regardless of whether I change the scope or start_url path. I have changed paths several times and restarted but it doesn't work.**

This is my manifest.json file:

```
{
"short_name": "Portal do Funcionário",
"name": "Portal do Funcionário",
"icons": [
    {
        "src": "favicon.ico",
        "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
        "type": "image/x-icon",
        "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
        "src": "logo192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
        "src": "maskable.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
        "src": "logo512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any maskable"
    }
],
"start_url": "/login",
"scope": "/",
"display": "standalone",
"theme_color": "#000000",
"background_color": "#ffffff",
"orientation": "landscape",
"prefer_related_applications": true
```

}

This is my service-worker.js file (service-worker file is from npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa):

```
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies';

clientsClaim();

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

registerRoute(({ request, url }) => {
    if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
        return false;
    }

    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/login')) {
        return false;
    }

    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}, createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html'));

registerRoute(
    ({ url }) => url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith('.png'),
    new StaleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: 'images',
        plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 })]
    })
);

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
        self.skipWaiting();
    }
});
```

**This is the error i get**
[image]